# Select Distinct value if does not exist elsewhere

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2012

I have a query, which if i run get the following results:
**Query:**

```
SELECT FROM Ticket WHERE ClosedOn IS NULL AND AssignedToTeamID = 1 AND TicketPriorityID = 2
```

**Result:**

[image: Query results]

Now what we want is the following query:
**Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ServerID, SiteID, 
    Case when(DetectorID-DetectorID%10) not in
               (Select Distinct SiteID FROM Ticket
                where SiteID is not NULL
                  and ClosedOn is null
                  and AssignedToTeamID = 1
                  and TicketPriorityID in (1, 2)) 
              THEN DetectorID-DetectorID%10
    end as DetectorID
FROM Ticket
where ClosedOn is null
  and AssignedToTeamID = 1
  and TicketPriorityID in (1, 2)
```

**Result:**
[image: Result of query]

Now, this is the result i want to get (Don't know why the first result is NULL, NULL, NULL). but that does not really matter now.

**My question:**

how do i get the query inside my code?
What i have now (Results in the first query):

```
        User user = ObjectContext.Users
        .Include("TeamMemberships")
        .First(u => u.UserID == userID);

        var teamIDs = user.TeamMemberships.Select(t => t.TeamID).ToList();
            var test = ObjectContext.Tickets
             .Include("TicketPriority")
             .Include("TicketStatu")
             .Include("TicketType")
             .Include("Server")
             .Include("Site")
             .Include("Detector")
             .Include("Detector.Site")
             .Include("Detector.Track")
             .Include("Team")
             .Include("User")
             .Include("User1")
             .Where(t => (withinTeam.HasValue ? withinTeam.Value ? teamIDs.Contains((int)t.AssignedToTeamID) : !teamIDs.Contains((int)t.AssignedToTeamID) : true))
             .Where(t => t.ClosedOn == null)
             .Where(t => t.TicketPriorityID == 1 || t.TicketPriorityID == 2);
            return test;
```

I don't know how to put cases/if statements in here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
ctx.Tickets
    .Where(t => t.ClosedOn == null &&
       t.AssignedToTeamId == 1 &&
       (t.TicketPriorityId == 1 || t.TicketPriorityId == 2))    
    .Select(t => new
    {
        t.ServerId, t.SiteId,
        DetectorId = t.DetectorId - t.DetectorId % 10
    })
    .Select(x => new
    {
       x.ServerId, x.SiteId,
       DetectorId = ctx.Tickets
          .Where(t => t.SiteId != null && t.ClosedOn == null &&
              t.AssignedToTeamId == 1 &&
              (t.TicketPriorityId == 1 || t.TicketPriorityId == 2))
          .Any(t => t.Id == x.DetectorId) ? 
          (int?) null : x.DetectorId
    })
    .ToArray();
```

If you need to combine it with `Include` then best way will be select IDs of rows that you need (I assume that number is small) and after that perform one more query with includes and `t => ids.Contains(t.Id)`. Or you can even place it in `Where` as sub query. Last way is to use manual joins (it can be required if you need both: custom calculated fields and simple joined fields).

Comment: Where does **t.Id** come from? and how do i return this. Just put variable x = infront of it, and then return that??

Comment: You can create your own class and use it instead of anonymous type. It's just an example of general approach. t in code below means condition in where.